# Nodejs Mongodb How to search in all fields using Regex?

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, express, find

I'm using a nodejs Express server and mongojs, and I want to search in all fields in the same time with a Regex expression.

I created an Index like this:

```
myCollection.createIndex({'$**':'text'});
```

And this is my 'find' request:

```
myCollection.find({$text:{$search:new RegExp('mySearchString')}}).limit(10, function(err, response) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

I got the error:

```
{"name":"MongoError","message":"\"$search\" had the wrong type. Expected String, found RegEx","waitedMS":0,"ok":0,"errmsg":"\"$search\" had the wrong type. Expected String, found RegEx","code":14}
```

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use a regex to search a text index, you'd have to use a big `$or` query to match against each field individually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its works fine with a '$or' solution :)